# Code block popup lacks scroll thumb

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When opening a code block in a question and scrolling the text the horizontal thumb appears but not the vertical one.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report. This is fixed in version 1.0.6.

[image]

Comment: I see it on 1.0.6 now.